# App not compatible with buildpack: Django + Python

Tags: django, heroku

When I click deployed button on heroku, I get some error, I have deployed this project for a certain period of time, and this time I deployed this error：

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

I already have requirnments.txt, runtime.txt, Procfile, I already added buildpack(heroku/python) in setting,
requirnments.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.10
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==3.1.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
Pillow==8.1.2
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pytz==2020.1
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
static3==0.7.0
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.7.3
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn APP_NAME.wsgi --log-file -
```

Any help or explanation is welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you push the source code from your master or main branch?

I was having the same problem as you when I pumped into this: [Deploy from local branch](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code).
So if you are not in main branch, you can either switch to one, or use `git push heroku your-current-branch:master`.\